# Check the checkbox dynamically using jquery and ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have the menu list in **div** tag where onPageLoad I am taking menus, submenus and displaying it.

Now I am calling ajax call when I click on the username it should check the checkbox which he has right to access the sub-menu.

The part which I have done is like the comparison of ids & keys.I am stuck on check the checkbox dynamically if both conditions meet.

HTML code looks like,

```
                     <% for(var i=0;i< data.length;i++){ 
                          if(data[i].has_child == 1) {
                       %>

                         <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><%= data[i].name %></div>

                            <% for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){ 

                            if(data[j].id == data[i].id && data[j].has_child == 0){ %>

                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="checkbox" id="rightCheck">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class = "rightCheck" value="<%= data[j].menu_id %>" ><%= data[j].name %></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <% }  }%>
                        </div>                          

                        <% }} %>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

I tried $(".rightCheck").prop("checked",true); but this checks the all checkboxes.
how to write condition for that?

Comment: Can you please show your AJAX code?

Comment: also add the rendered HTML. Not the code

Comment: On success of ajax i have code like ,var key_id=document.getElementsByClassName('rightCheck');for (var i = 0, j = 0,k=j; i<data.length, j < data.length; i++, j++) {
if (data[j].id == data[i].id && data[j].has_child == 0) {for(var k = 0; k< key_id.length ;k++){if(data[j].menu_id == key_id[k].value){
//Here i want condition to set checkbox to true 
$(".rightCheck").prop("checked",true);} } } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AJAX code when you get the id in AJAX success just match that id with checkbox's id.

```
success: function(){
  //Now loop through checkbox
   $(".rightCheck").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id") == id) //check if checkbox id match
    {
      $(this).prop("checked",true);
    }
   });  
}
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as approved if it helped. @KiranDevkar